# Game Settings file prob

Tags: java, for-loop, fileinputstream

Hi I'm working on a settings loader system and it doesn't want to work, I have tried different ways of doing it and this one looks the best, except it not working, can I please have some help because I need this done by the end of the day.

Here is the code:

```
public GameSettings getGameSettings() throws Exception
{
    Resolution GameResolution;
    GameSettings gs = new GameSettings(true, true, false, 50, new Resolution(800, 600));

    for(int k = 0; k < lines.size(); k++)
    {
        String[] s1 = lines.get(k).split("=");

        if(s1[0].equals("volume"))
        {
            gs.setVolume(Integer.parseInt(s1[1]));
        }
        if(s1[0].equals("musicOn"))
        {
            gs.setMusicOn(Boolean.parseBoolean(s1[1]));
        }
        if(s1[0].equals("soundOn"))
        {
            gs.setSoundOn(Boolean.parseBoolean(s1[1]));
        }
        if(s1[0].equals("aOpenGL"))
        {
            gs.setAOpenGL(Boolean.parseBoolean(s1[1]));
        }
        if(s1[0].equals("GameRes"))
        {
            String[] s2 = s1[1].split("x");
            GameResolution = new Resolution(Integer.parseInt(s2[1]), Integer.parseInt(s2[1]));
            gs.setGameResolution(GameResolution);
        }
        if(s1[0].startsWith("#"))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            System.err.println("WARNING: Unknow setting in settings file ('" + s1[0] + "')");
            continue;
        }
    }

    return gs;
}
```

, this is the 'settings.dat' file content:

```
#************************** Settings
#Settings file version 1.5
musicOn=false
volume=75
soundOn=true
aOpenGL=false
GameRes=1000x800
#end of settings file
```

and finally the console output:

```
WARNING: Unknow setting in settings file ('musicOn')
WARNING: Unknow setting in settings file ('volume')
WARNING: Unknow setting in settings file ('soundOn')
WARNING: Unknow setting in settings file ('aOpenGL')
WARNING: Unknow setting in settings file ('GameRes')
```

Comment: I put `*` in the way of the name of the game

Comment: It might be more useful later on to parse the file into a Map of some kind (probably a HashMap) so if you need to modify any settings while in the game you can do so on the fly.  You can then the file out when the program exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, in your code for any non-commented line you print a warning.

I guess you actually wanted to use `else if` instead of `if` every time, as in your code the final `else` refers to the `if` above only.

Comment: Think that might of worked, no more error outputs, let me just check

Answer (score 2):

You need to chain those `if`s with `else`s.

```
if (str.equals("a")) {
  ...
} else if (str.equals("b")) {
  ...
} else {
  // failed to match anything
}
```

Otherwise, *all* the ifs are evaluated each time the loop runs, so the `Unkown` message will show for all lines that are not comments, regardless of whether they matched something before or not.